# Android Google Maps | Get only directions route angle and distance

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm need to use GoogleMaps for an android app

1. I need to build an android app that sends request to GoogleMaps API and recive only the list of directions (Turn right in 400meters at the next..) without showing any map
2. How to I update the list by user movement ? 
   (You currently passed first turn, heading to second turn.. 800 meters to next turn.. 400 meters to next turn)
3. If in answer 2 I get only String with "Left,Right,North.." How do I get the turn angle ? 
   (45-125 will be right, 90 will be absolute right)

I would like to hear about how to optimize the update ( There are 4 ways to use threads in android so I've heard )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listen for Location Updates using requestLocationUpdates().

http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html#StartUpdates